# Are there any tool can check the PhoneGap app performance?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, performance-testing

We hire PhoneGap developer to build an app. After the app finished, we found the app speed is very low and it hangs frequently. when we ask the freelance, he says our server is responsible for this issue.

However, I believe this is not correct because I use a same hosting company with other apps and websites without any problem plus we have only 3 users use this app currently.

Are there any tool can check the app performance? (something like *Google PageSpeed* for websites). If there are no testing tool like this, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Client side: you can go for [Chrome Dev Tools Remote Debugging](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging) or [Intel XDK](http://xdk-software.intel.com/) which has "Profile" option
- Server side: you can just record and replay your application network activity either for single user or simulating larger number of users using i.e. [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/), check out [Load Testing Mobile Apps Made Easy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-mobile-apps-made-easy) article for insights.